# Tensorflow object detection API: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train Tensorflow object detection API on google colab. However it is giving me the CUDA out of memory error right after step: 0 in the training process.
I have installed tensorflow 1.15 as object detection API is not available in the tensorflow 2.x.
The exact same steps do work on my local Jupyter on CPU, and I'm not sure why the training does not even start on colab.

I run the following before the error

```
!python3 /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={model_pipline}\
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
```

Output Error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
W0531 13:25:33.996640 140410072971136 model_lib.py:717] Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I0531 13:25:33.996945 140410072971136 config_util.py:523] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0531 13:25:33.997089 140410072971136 config_util.py:523] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: 1
I0531 13:25:33.997240 140410072971136 config_util.py:523] Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: 1
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
I0531 13:25:33.997398 140410072971136 config_util.py:523] Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting load_pretrained: True
I0531 13:25:33.997565 140410072971136 config_util.py:523] Maybe overwriting load_pretrained: True
INFO:tensorflow:Ignoring config override key: load_pretrained
I0531 13:25:33.997698 140410072971136 config_util.py:533] Ignoring config override key: load_pretrained
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
W0531 13:25:33.998711 140410072971136 model_lib.py:733] Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
INFO:tensorflow:create_estimator_and_inputs: use_tpu False, export_to_tpu False
I0531 13:25:33.998897 140410072971136 model_lib.py:768] create_estimator_and_inputs: use_tpu False, export_to_tpu False
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'final_training/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7fb36c4dc400>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
I0531 13:25:33.999563 140410072971136 estimator.py:212] Using config: {'_model_dir': 'final_training/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7fb36c4dc400>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7fb34c3da598>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
W0531 13:25:33.999892 140410072971136 model_fn.py:630] Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7fb34c3da598>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
I0531 13:25:34.000695 140410072971136 estimator_training.py:186] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
I0531 13:25:34.000978 140410072971136 training.py:612] Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
I0531 13:25:34.001283 140410072971136 training.py:700] Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
W0531 13:25:34.028567 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0531 13:25:34.070708 140410072971136 dataset_builder.py:84] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
W0531 13:25:34.077606 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/data/python/ops/interleave_ops.py:77: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_determinstic`.
W0531 13:25:34.077923 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/data/python/ops/interleave_ops.py:77: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_determinstic`.
2020-05-31 13:25:36.022795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-05-31 13:25:36.073569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:25:36.074655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.090393: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.296904: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.393112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.418127: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.678324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:36.811132: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:25:37.344874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-31 13:25:37.345175: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:25:37.346326: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:25:37.347195: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:77: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0531 13:25:48.383893 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:77: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/utils/ops.py:493: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
W0531 13:25:48.520766 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/utils/ops.py:493: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:259: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0531 13:25:54.216460 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:259: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:174: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
W0531 13:25:59.079778 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:174: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
I0531 13:25:59.097109 140410072971136 estimator.py:1148] Calling model_fn.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:2802: Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
W0531 13:25:59.139202 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:2802: Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I0531 13:26:01.037326 140410072971136 regularizers.py:99] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I0531 13:26:01.055346 140410072971136 regularizers.py:99] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I0531 13:26:01.055730 140410072971136 convolutional_box_predictor.py:156] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/utils/spatial_transform_ops.py:428: calling crop_and_resize_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) with box_ind is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
box_ind is deprecated, use box_indices instead
W0531 13:26:02.010904 140410072971136 deprecation.py:506] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/utils/spatial_transform_ops.py:428: calling crop_and_resize_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) with box_ind is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
box_ind is deprecated, use box_indices instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:1666: flatten (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.flatten instead.
W0531 13:26:02.647731 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tf_slim/layers/layers.py:1666: flatten (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.flatten instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I0531 13:26:02.650445 140410072971136 regularizers.py:99] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I0531 13:26:02.673438 140410072971136 regularizers.py:99] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
W0531 13:26:02.717383 140410072971136 variables_helper.py:161] Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[360]], model variable shape: [[12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
W0531 13:26:02.717535 140410072971136 variables_helper.py:161] Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1024, 360]], model variable shape: [[1024, 12]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
W0531 13:26:02.717698 140410072971136 variables_helper.py:161] Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[91]], model variable shape: [[4]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
W0531 13:26:02.717808 140410072971136 variables_helper.py:161] Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1024, 91]], model variable shape: [[1024, 4]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
W0531 13:26:02.718722 140410072971136 variables_helper.py:164] Variable [global_step] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py:347: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

W0531 13:26:04.374737 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /content/cricket_detect/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py:347: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
I0531 13:26:09.405748 140410072971136 estimator.py:1150] Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
I0531 13:26:09.407379 140410072971136 basic_session_run_hooks.py:541] Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
I0531 13:26:11.816042 140410072971136 monitored_session.py:240] Graph was finalized.
2020-05-31 13:26:11.816602: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-05-31 13:26:11.830249: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2300000000 Hz
2020-05-31 13:26:11.830685: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x11893480 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-31 13:26:11.830738: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-05-31 13:26:11.970569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.971684: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x118932c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-31 13:26:11.971721: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, Compute Capability 6.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.973064: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.973960: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.3285
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974056: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974154: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974204: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974251: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974290: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974335: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-31 13:26:11.974520: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.975454: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.976268: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.980340: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:11.982313: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-31 13:26:11.982373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2020-05-31 13:26:11.982394: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2020-05-31 13:26:11.983769: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.984820: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-31 13:26:11.985809: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2020-05-31 13:26:11.985880: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15216 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from final_training/model.ckpt-0
I0531 13:26:11.988441 140410072971136 saver.py:1284] Restoring parameters from final_training/model.ckpt-0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py:1069: get_checkpoint_mtimes (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file utilities to get mtimes.
W0531 13:26:23.509253 140410072971136 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py:1069: get_checkpoint_mtimes (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file utilities to get mtimes.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
I0531 13:26:24.215053 140410072971136 session_manager.py:500] Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
I0531 13:26:24.414194 140410072971136 session_manager.py:502] Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into final_training/model.ckpt.
I0531 13:26:30.769316 140410072971136 basic_session_run_hooks.py:606] Saving checkpoints for 0 into final_training/model.ckpt.
2020-05-31 13:26:35.972650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-05-31 13:26:37.554192: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.7392851, step = 0
I0531 13:26:45.659757 140410072971136 basic_session_run_hooks.py:262] loss = 1.7392851, step = 0
2020-05-31 13:26:58.824769: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.824930: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825060: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825093: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 7730940928
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825191: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 6957846528 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825218: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6957846528
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825280: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 6262061568 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825308: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 6262061568
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825417: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 5635855360 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825448: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5635855360
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825539: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 5072269824 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825567: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5072269824
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825638: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:893] failed to alloc 4565042688 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-05-31 13:26:58.825667: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_host_allocator.h:44] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4565042688
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your batch size = 1? This worked for me and I haven't received the OOM error on Colab since